# Python - Improve urllib performance

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, parallel-processing, urllib

I have a huge dataframe with 1M+ rows and I want to collect some information from Nominatim using URL. I have used the geopy library before, but I had some problems, so I decide to use the API instead.

But, my code is running too slow to get the requests.

URLs sample:

```
  urls = ['https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Suape&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en',
 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Kwangyang&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en',
 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Luanda&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en',
 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Ancona&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en',
 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Xiamen&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en',
 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Jebel%20Dhanna/Ruwais&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en',
 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Nemrut%20Bay%20&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en']
```

**Sample code below**

For a single url for test:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import json

req = urllib.request.Request(url, None)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
page = f.read()
nominatim = json.loads(page.decode())
result = nominatim[0]['address']['country']
```

So, I created a function to apply in my dataframe column that have location address (eg. Suape, Kwangyang, Luanda...):

```
def country(address):
try:
    if ' ' in address:
        address = address.replace(' ', '%20')
        url = f'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q={address}&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en'
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, None)
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        page = f.read()
        nominatim = json.loads(page.decode())
        result = nominatim[0]['address']['country']
    else:
        url = f'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q={address}&format=json&limit=1&accept-language=en'
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, None)
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        page = f.read()
        nominatim = json.loads(page.decode())
        result = nominatim[0]['address']['country']
    return result
except:
    pass
```

It takes too long to run. I have tried to optmize my function, try different approaches to apply to column, and now I'm trying to improve the requests, because is the part that takes more time to conclude. Any suggestions? I have tried threading, but not works as expected (maybe I have not done properly). I test asyncio also, but the code doesn't worked.

Thank you!

**Edit:** I'll only use the requests in unique values of this column, that corresponding to approx. 4K rows. But, even in 4K rows, the code takes too much time to run.

Comment: You need to use multithreading to speed this up, otherwise you waste too much time waiting for the API to respond. Elaborate on "but not works as expected".

Comment: I used multithreading based on another StackOverflow post, but the time to run keeps the same. I never used multithreading before, maybe I doing it wrong.